# React Native iOS Release build stuck on old code but Debug build works fine

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build

When I try to build my React Native App from `XCode` in `Release mode` to check before launch it to production it get stuck in old code. No matter what change I do in my JS file that it won't do it. In Debug mode it doesn't happen, just works fine like it should.

Example:

I change a label in any of my JS files like a title of some menu and it will work when I use `react-native run-ios` or if I press on "Play" button of XCode if in the scheme "Debug" is checked. If instead, I check "Release" it charge an old version of my app I don't even know with certainly which version is.

I have tried to launch to production but still being the old version.

So, now a day I can't upload new version due to no matter what changes I do, the release mode ignores it.

I have tried to generate a new `main.jsbundle`, I have cleaned build with `Shift + CMD + K` and I aso have reinstalled my `npm` with no solution.

Do you have any idea?

EDIT:

Does the file "AppDelegate.m" have anything to do with it?

This is my AppDelegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"BottomNavigation"
                                            initialProperties:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you try with this ios re-bundler command: `react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/assets`

Comment: Hi @Kuray-FreakyCoder- . It created a new main.jsbundle but when I build and run still not changing anything.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example with me?

Comment: I don't really know how could I share a reproducible example. Just my app ignore any change I would do if the scheme is in Release mode. If I run the react-native run-ios command or put the scheme in Debug mode it will work as should work. And to upload to the app store i need the Release mode right.

Comment: what i do to test rn ios app is: build archive and upload then test using TestFlight app

Comment: Yes, I do the same and the app I upload to TestFlight is built with the old code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I posted here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59029751/8898886

Finally I found the solution.

The problem was that the main.jsbundle I was generating was placing in the wrong place having 2 main.jsbundle at the same time, the old and corrupted and the right one.

I had the right one outside /ios/ProjectName and the old one there. I just had to apply this snippet which would generate a new and clean `main.jsbundle`:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/assets
```

and then get the file main.jsbundle and the assets folder and place them inside /ios/ProjectName

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Before archive stop already running node
and start server and now make archive

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```