# Hot Reload isn't working for iOS simulator

Tags: react-native

My simulator is not getting the newest JavaScript changes unless I run the following:

```
npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/assets
```

This is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59029769/5648619).

This also means that I am not getting the newest changes through Hot Reload.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I met the same issue, did you find the solution?
BTW, it works well on real devices.