# Xcode not reflecting latest app codes from react-native

Tags: xcode, react-native, app-store, app-store-connect

EDIT:

Okay turns out this is not a problem with AppStore i ran the app from Xcode release mode and i got the same old version running on the simulator i don't know why but Xcode is not running the latest jsbundle.

now i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977223/using-react-native-ios-release-build-doesnt-load-new-code-but-the-version-does) question with the same problem and tried following it i ran this command:
`react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/assets` and put the newly generated `main.jsbundle` inside `/ios/ProjectName` but still when i ran the code from Xcode it gives me an old version
i also tried cleaning and rebuilding and removing derived data and building again with same result

i recently uploaded an app to the Apple App Store but seems to be having issues with it here's the case i uploaded the app and it got approved and says its ready for sell but when i go to the app store and download the app it is just the previous version of the app and i don't see all the new changes made on the app...this is kind of strange for me i have also uploaded a new logo on the new version release and the logo is updated..the version is also updated on the app store listing the previous one was 1.0 this one shows 1.1 and the "Whats new" section is also updated...i have also changed the preview and screenshots with this new version that is also reflected on the app store listing but only when i download the app i get the previous version.

i tried going to my app store connect and then Activity and i see my build is there with a correct uploaded date and build numbers...is there something i am missing here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Here is a detailed trial-and-error process trying to pin down which step is crucial to resolve the issue.

I start from the code base where `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release` does reflect new changes in the code base. Each subsequent round follows the previous round, i.e., the previous round's end state might affect the next round.

### Round 1

- Remove `main.jsbundle` from both Xcode and the file system.
- Make changes to the react native code base.
- Run `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`
- *FAIL*, new changes not reflected in the build.

### Round 2

- Try `npm start -- --reset-cache`
- Run `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`
- *FAIL*, new changes not reflected in the build.

### Round 3

- Try "Cmd + Shift + K" within Xcode to clean build.
- Run `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`
- *FAIL*, new changes not reflected in the build.

### Round 4

- Run `react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/your_app_name/main.jsbundle`
- Run `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`
- *FAIL*, new changes not reflected in the build.

### Round 5

- In Xcode, manually add the `main.jsbundle` file to your app folder. In your project, right click on the folder baring your app's name, choose "Add file to your_app_name", and add `main.jsbundle` in the app folder. Note that the bundle we add here was created in Round 4.
- Run `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`. In the output message during command execution, a new message shows up: `"Copying /.../your_app_name/ios/your_app_name/main.jsbundle"`.
- **SUCCCESS**, new changes are showing now. This suggests that the bundle created in Round 4 is used for this build, instead of some previous version cached somewhere.

### Round 6

- Make another change in the react native code base.
- Directly run `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release` without building the bundle manually. The copy message does not show up.
- *FAIL*, new changes not reflected in the build. Note that `main.jsbundle` exists in both Xcode and the file system.

### Round 7

- Run `watchman watch-del-all` to clean cache of `watchman`.
- Run `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`. The copy message does not show up.
- *FAIL*, new changes not reflected in the build.

### Round 8

- Run `react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/your_app_name/main.jsbundle` to rebuild a bundle.
- Without tinkering with Xcode, directly run `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`. This time, the copy message shows up.
- **SUCCCESS**, the latest changes are showing now.

### Conclusion

At least on my laptop, manually building an offline bundle is required for each new release build to reflect the latest changes in the react native code base. Building the bundle only works if the bundle is added to the app folder in Xcode. It seems that we only need to add the bundle to Xcode once.

Also a big caveat is that the behavior might be different with a different Xcode version.

### Versions I am working with

- macOS Catalino 10.15.6
- Xcode 11.6
- react-native 0.61.5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be because it was running a cached version of the app so it got solved by doing `npm start --reset-cache`

Comment: Ow i see...but in my case the project was actually ejected from expo and whenever i made changes to my project i needed to run expo publish to update the main jsbundle file which xcode uses.